# How can I use GObject Introspection to generate Java bindings?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, wrapper, glib, gobject-introspection

I need to use the GLib library in the [spice-gtk](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/spice/spice-gtk). Since, it’s a GLib library, that means I can use GObject introspection to generate Java bindings. I have found out that I need to get GIR XML files from either compiling or from prebuilt libraries [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/gir1.2-spiceclientglib-2.0). That’s cool and all, but how do I actually generate the Java bindings?

I‘ve looked at a questions asked about this and documentation online, but it doesn’t seem to tell you how to actually start the process.

Comment: The project you linked consists of several submodules (see ["project contents"](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/spice/spice-gtk#project-content)). Do you want to wrap the spice-GTK program itself (this seems pointless) or rather the underlying spice_client_glib_lib library? Do you just want to talk to a running Spice client? In which case you could get away with using Glib introspection and a native Java Glib client.

Comment: The focus on "without or without source code" is also irrelevant. At the end of the day your Java process will load a dynamic library that is compiled from source code, either on the same machine or a very distant one. Having the source code available just means you can knead the library interface to suit SWIG better. For example by providing nice constructor functions instead of asking clients to create complex memory layouts up front.

Comment: I realize that I don’t need everything in the repo, but I didn’t know what all I needed. I would like to do everything that this guide can do: https://github.com/Rylern/SpiceGTK-tutorial. My end goal is to have a Java program that can get picture output and input mouse and keyboard. So, I‘m assuming I would need the glib and gtk libraries, but you’re saying maybe just glib? How would I just use the glib library?

Comment: I also tried reverse engineering https://github.com/iiordanov/remote-desktop-clients/tree/master/aSPICE-app, but it’s overwhelming for me. However it uses JNI is how I need to do it I believe

Comment: I think you need a better understanding of the software stack offered here. there is a core spice_client_glib_lib library that speaks the Spice protocol, and a spice-GTK library that allows interacting with a Spice session. Both support GObject introspection (a language-agnostic format that describes a GLib interface), which should allow you to generate fairly high-level Java bindings and use those in a Java+GTK program. If that does not work then you would have to feed either `spice-client.h` or `spice-client-gtk.h` to SWIG. Depends on whether you want to use the GTK widget or do it yourself

Comment: But before all that, you should clarify your goal. How much of the resulting application should be Java code and/or what bits do you want to add? If you're just going to be embedding a spice-GTK widget in a GTK application the use of Java only adds complexity.

Comment: If I had the choice I would just use C to manage the VM, but I have to use Java because I‘m making a Spigot plugin. I don‘t actually need any of the GUI stuff because the graphics output will be displayed in-game. What I imagined the end-product to look like is the Spice-gtk library would be wrapped in Java (don‘t need the gtk part) and I could make Java methods using the already wrapped spice library to get picture output, keyboard and mouse input, etc

Comment: Then you want to interact with the core Spice client library and forego the Gtk integration, which mostly hooks up the display and input devices to the session.

Comment: It’s not clear where the libraries are. I just need glib then? So would I just be using what is under `src/`? How would I wrap that to use it in my Java plugin?

Comment: You compile the source code to a native library plus a GIR XML files that describe the interface. You can then generate Java code that adheres to the GI protocol and have relatively painless interop with Java, or you write native code that uses GLib and the Spice client directly and you write Java bindings for _that_.

Comment: The XML files are beyond my knowledge. How do you get those? I know when I compile the whole spice-gtk source, there are glib and gtk .so files and also some other files.  I haven’t payed attention to the other files generated. Maybe I should wait until I‘m back at my computer. I get what you’re saying for the last part. That is what I had in mind, but I don’t know if I should do the first or second option

Comment: They are generated as part of the compilation process, if you ask for them. Or you just grab them from [a prebuilt package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/gir1.2-spiceclientglib-2.0).

Comment: @Botje Should we continue this in chat or no? I still have a lot of questions

Comment: As it stands this question is too broad and too vague to be of use to anyone who stumbles across it. You should ask one or more new questions that are focused on one specific, concrete problem.

Comment: @Botje I need to work on that. I treat SO like Reddit. I will change this to just ask one question and then maybe create more

Comment: @Botje Are you able to help me any on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was found on the [GNOME Discourse Forums](https://discourse.gnome.org/t/how-exactly-do-i-use-gobject-introspection-to-generate-bindings/19471/2?u=anston_sorensen). All that needed to be done was search on Google for "Java GObject introspection bindings generator."

Several tools have been created throughout the years that generate Java bindings with GObject introspection. They include [JGIR](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/JGIR) (which was one click away on the GObject guide), [gir2java](https://github.com/octachoron/gir2java), and [Java-GI](https://github.com/jwharm/java-gi).

Java-GI is the most prominent today. This tool has the advantage of it using the new [Foreign Function & Memory API](https://openjdk.org/jeps/442). The disadvantage is that the API is experimental, and it of course doesn't use JNI which would be better for backward-compatible Java apps/plugins.

Unfortunately, there seems to be no other tool that can use GObject introspection besides Java-GI if someone wishes to use JNI. The only options left would be to manually create a library with JNI or use a wrapper generator like [SWIG](https://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Java.html#java_overview) to generate a library.